# What are the reasons why volume control wouldn't work for Chromecast?

Tags: android, google-cast

I'm using the MediaRouter library to change the volume of a Chromecast Device. After some time the volume commands don't work anymore.

```
mRoute.requestSetVolume(volume);
```

There is a selected route.

Tracing the code I found that it does send the volume change packet.

It also doesn't work from the System UI. Changing from the volume buttons will move the Seek pointer of the volume dialog, but after 3 or 4 seconds it reverts to it's previous position.

It only does seem to work from the Google Cast app.

Does the Google Cast app use a different protocol or api to change the volume of the Chromecast?

This was tested with Chromecast Audio and Chromecast v2.

Comment: Google Cast App uses Cast SDK to manage that.